# Error in sonar : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory error in sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using Sonar on Tomcat and using on a java project using ant.

when ever i run the sonar in command prompt I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

In previous project its working fine but when i configure a new project i am getting this error..

```
 <sonar:sonar  key="dk.logica:pensab" version="1.0" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

        <sources>
            <path location="${jpa.base.dir}/src" />

            <path location="${ws.base.dir}/config/xsd" />
             <fileset dir="${ws.base.dir}/src" >
      <exclude name="**/BuildErrorCode.java"/>
    </fileset>

         </sources>

          <property key="sonar.projectName" value="Pensab" />
       <!--   <property key="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
          <property key="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="ZTest/cobertura/xmlreport" />
          <property key="sonar.cobertura.reportPath" value="ZTest/cobertura/coveragereport/coverage.xml" /> -->
          <property key="sonar.java.source" value="1.6" />
          <property key="sonar.java.target" value="1.6" />

          <property key="java.specification.version" value="1.6" />
          <property key="java.runtime.version" value="1.6" />
          <property key="java.vm.version" value="1.6" />
          <property key="ant.java.version" value="1.6" />



          <tests>
            <path location="${ws.base.dir}/src" />
          </tests>

          <binaries>
            <path refid="allclass" />

            <path location="${ws.base.dir}/config/xsd" />

          </binaries>

          <libraries>
            <path refid="alljars"  />
            <path location="${ws.base.dir}/config/xsd" />

          </libraries>

        </sonar:sonar>
      </target>
```

Complete error

```
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant version 1.8.1 compiled on April 30 2010
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 1.0
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/D:/JavaWorld/ContinuousIntegration/Provider    /workspace/WS/sonar-ant-task-1.0.jar
[sonar:sonar] Sonar work directory: D:\JavaWorld\ContinuousIntegration\Provider\workspace\WS\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] Sonar server: http://localhost:8080/sonar/
[sonar:sonar] Sonar version: 2.8
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Database dialect class org.sonar.jpa.dialect.Derby
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Initializing Hibernate
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(2) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(3) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(4) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(5) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(6) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(7) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(8) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(9) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docum
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(10) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(11) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(12) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(14) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(15) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(16) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(17) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(18) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(19) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(20) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(21) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(22) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(23) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(24) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(25) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(26) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(27) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(28) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(29) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(31) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(34) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(39) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the docu
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Execution environment: Ant Apache Ant version 1.8.1 compiled on April 30 2010
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  -------------  Analyzing MyProject
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Selected quality profile : [name=MyProj,language=java]
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Compare over 5 days (2012-03-04)
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Compare over 30 days (2012-02-08)
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Configure maven plugins...
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Sensor AsynchronousMeasuresSensor...
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Sensor AsynchronousMeasuresSensor done: 1609 ms
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 2547 ms
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Sensor SquidSensor...

BUILD FAILED
D:\JavaWorld\ContinuousIntegration\Provider\workspace\WS\sonar-build.xml:80: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:358)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:443)
    at     org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.hasProjectBytecodeFiles(SquidSensor.java:109)
    at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.getMainBytecodeFiles(SquidSensor.java:95)
    at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.analyzeMainSources(SquidSensor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.analyse(SquidSensor.java:62)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:80)
    at org.sonar.batch.ProjectBatch.execute(ProjectBatch.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.analyzeModule(Batch.java:164)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.analyzeModules(Batch.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:62)
    at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:121)
    at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.delegateExecution(SonarTask.java:167)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:151)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Anyone suggest me a solution ?

Comment: where does the parameter 'directory' point.

Comment: There is no attribute called directory in sonar!

Comment: please add the ant target, that you use to invoke sonar analysis

Comment: and could you add the whole stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your are using an old Version of the ant task ([1.0](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task+1.0) if you can update your sonar server you should do so and update the ant task as well).

But your problem lies here (which will not be fixed by the new version of the plugin):

```
<fileset dir="${ws.base.dir}/src" >
    <exclude name="**/BuildErrorCode.java"/>
</fileset>
```

will put a list of java files into `<source> ... </source>`

These would not be directories (because they are files) and cause that error.

The [doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task) says for sources:

```
  <!-- source directories (required) -->
  <sources>
    <path location="..." />
  </sources>
```

You can't put files per fileset in there. Only directories.

Comment: so can i use multiple <source> ... </source>  and how can i avoid some unwanted files in a src ?

Comment: @Raj you can have multiple sources, but they have to be directories. You can exclude special files in the configuration in the server or via the [sonar.exclusion property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error recently after moving sonarqube binary directory. Had to kill all `java` process from activity monitor and run `./sonar.sh start` to fix the issue.